# Best way to convert query results to domain entities

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, knex.js

I am using Knex.js to build SQL queries. It works well but I need to convert my query results into domain entities (a type representing an object from the domain) for my graphql resolvers. I used Knex to avoid using an ORM because a number of people online made it seem like an ORM will make queries more difficult. My current best idea is to follow the Repository pattern and have the ugly code for converting results to classes in the repo class. Better ideas are welcome :)

Comment: You can extract the mapping behavior to a specific class or namespace for each of your entities: check out [this link](https://khalilstemmler.com/articles/typescript-domain-driven-design/repository-dto-mapper/#Data-Mappers) for more info. Whether to perform the conversion within the repository or as a separate step within your controller logic is probably personal preference. I personally like to have the data fetching and entity conversions separate and coordinate them explicitly.

Comment: Thanks @j_m4rtinez, that link was beautiful

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want to just make a db-call based on GraphQL query (which is mean you already have db and want to use simple ORM instead of EF for example).

I don't know which platform do you have, but if you have .net, you can take a look [NReco.GraphQL](https://www.nrecosite.com/graphql_to_sql_database.aspx). It allows to set db-connection and define graphql schema in the json file (graphql schmea to db-table including relation between schemas), definately, it's worth take a look.

Comment: unfortunately in this project I am working within node. I have been looking to get more into .net though so I will definitely check out NReco.GraphQL for .net applications